# the procedure entry point ?_Xmem@tr1@std@@YAXXZ could not be located in the dynamic link library MSVCP90D.dll

Tags: c++

I have installed VS2008 FeaturePack so as to work with regular expressions in C++. However when I execute the program i get the following error.

> the procedure entry point ?_Xmem@tr1@std@@YAXXZ could not be located in the dynamic link library MSVCP90D.dll.

How could have gone wrong?

Thanks and Regards,
SS

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your program is trying to run with older version of CRT. I have two MSVCP90D.dll files on my machine.

I think that version 9.00.21022.8 came with Visual Studio 2008 and version 9.00.30729.1 came with SP1. The first one doesn't have TR1 but the other one does.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My PC got restored to the previous checkpoint, hence the changes were undone, so I had to reinstall the FeaturePack so that it accessed the new version of dll file.

Comment: Consider installing SP1, it contains FeaturePack and bug fixes.